# Trace map for separated morphism of non-singular varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I read about for any separable morphism of non-singular varieties $f:X'\to X$, one can define a homomorphism $\text{Tr}:f_*(\Omega_{X'}^q) \to \Omega_{X}^q$,so that the map $\Omega_{X}^q \to f_*(\Omega_{X'}^q) $splits. But I didn't find a reference about how is it done?

Comment: I believe that Serre's "Algebraic Groups and Class Fields" contains this.

Comment: @JesseSilliman: I believe Serre does this when $X$ and $X'$ are curves; in particular, $q$ is at most $1$.  In fact, this suffices to compute the trace maps at codimension $1$ points of $X$, i.e., away from a closed subset of codimension $2$.  If the sheaves involved are $S2$, as they are in this question, that suffices.  This is essentially what de Jong and I say in our erratum.  Unfortunately, in the original article, the sheaves are not always $S2$.

Comment: Just to make sure I completely understand this... Doesn't one need to require that the degree of $f$ is not divisible by the characteristic of the field one is working on? Otherwise the natural map $\mathcal{O}_X\longrightarrow f_\ast\mathcal{O}_{X'}$ can't be split by the trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not mind a reference that contains a serious mistake, you can use the following.

MR1716049 (2000h:13016) Reviewed 
Zannier, Umberto 
A note on traces of differential forms. (English summary) 
J. Pure Appl. Algebra 142 (1999), no. 1, 91–97. 
13N05 (14F10) 
[article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404998000450)

Part of the mistake is corrected in the following erratum.

MR2507247 (2010h:14007) Reviewed 
de Jong, A. J.(1-CLMB); Starr, Jason(1-SUNYS) 
Erratum: Cubic fourfolds and spaces of rational curves [MR2085418]. 
 
Illinois J. Math. 52 (2008), no. 1, 345–346. 
14C05 (14E08)

Comment: To spell out the counterexample in the paper a bit better, let $\mathrm{char(k)} \neq 0$, let $X' = \mathrm{Spec} k[u,v]$ and let $X = \mathrm{Spec} k[u^2, uv, v^2]$, with the obvious map. Then $Tr(u dv)$ should be $2 u dv$. We have $2 u dv = (u/v) d(v^2) = 2 d(uv) - (v/u) d(u^2)$, so $2 u dv$ is regular on the smooth part of $X$, but it isn't regular at the singular point.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the proof in Zannier would be correct if Zannier imposed that $X$ was non-singular, not just normal? (And, therefore, Zannier's paper is a correct answer to the stated question.)

Comment: @DavidSpeyer: Yes, I think that is correct.  However, for smooth schemes, I think one can just use Serre's  "Algebraic Groups and Class Fields", as Jesse Silliman notes above.